# Set width of custom UIView nib to it's parent CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, xib, nib

This is what I have:

A Collection View with 2 columns with each an equal distance apart.

Each cell loads SmallCardView.xib. The SmallCardView contains a square image with some text below.

The problem:

I want the width of the view to match that of it's parent (the cell). This is best illustrated by comparing screen sizes

[image: Screen size comparison]

As you can see above, the cell (purple outline) sizes correctly on both screens but the SmallCardView remains the same size

Here is the code in my Collection View Controller:

viewDidLoad -

```
private let spacing: CGFloat = 20.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: spacing, bottom: spacing, right: spacing)
    self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

sizeForItemAt -

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let numberOfItemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2
    let spacingBetweenCells: CGFloat = 20

    let totalSpacing = (2 * self.spacing) + ((numberOfItemsPerRow - 1) * spacingBetweenCells) // Amount of total spacing in a row

    if let collection = self.collectionView {
        let width = (collection.bounds.width - totalSpacing)/numberOfItemsPerRow
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width * 1.2)
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide code you use to embed `SmallCardView.xib` inside your cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed view with constraints to edges as:

```swift
extension UIView {

    func makeEdges(to view: UIView, useMargins: Bool = false) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        return [
            (useMargins ? layoutMarginsGuide.leftAnchor : leftAnchor).constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            (useMargins ? layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor : rightAnchor).constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
            (useMargins ? layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor : topAnchor).constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            (useMargins ? layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor : bottomAnchor).constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ]
    }

    func edges(to view: UIView, useMargins: Bool = false) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(makeEdges(to: view, useMargins: useMargins))
    }
}
```

And use it as:

```swift
let cardView = ...
cardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let cell = ...
cell.contentView.addSubview(cardView)
cell.contentView.edges(to: cardView, useMargins: true)
```

Answer (score -1):

First take collectionview from storyboard. Set it's constraints like as below :-

1. Leading space to container - 20
2. Trailing space to container - 20
3. Top space to container - 20
4. Bottom space to container - 20

Then select collectionview and remove lines padding that is default 10. So, update with 20. So, cellpadding should be 10 each side.

Then Go to the viewcontroller file and add all 3 delegates 
 1. UICollectionViewDelegate
 2. UICollectionViewDataSource
 3. UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Then add following code in your swift file :-

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

       return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.size.width - 60) / 2, height: (self.view.frame.size.width - 60) / 2)

   }
```